# My nav bar suddenly scrolls left of the page, testing the Get button. Any idea why?

Tags: javascript

http://birdbreath.com/bb/sticky_navbb4.html

It begins the scroll properly, setting the right classes and suddenly scrolls left off the page.

I have tried a variety of things including overflow-x: hidden; .

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: why your body has a overflow:hidden ?

Comment: It works properly in the Chrome Web Maker extension. The Chrome Dev tools found no errors.

Comment: I was attempting to add it in a variety of places,hoping it would help.

Comment: I couldn't see your page's problem..there is page without any scroll both in cherome and firefox

Answer (score 0):

Did you add height and width property into your class? Could you clarify more, what do you want?

Comment: This is a question, not an answer. Please don't add questions or comments as answers.

Comment: Well add height & width property along with overflow property

Comment: I eventually want it to scroll to and remain visible at the top of the Get page. And scroll to the top of he home page and disappear which it does. The ses an the left of the Get page is a test of my visibility script.

Comment: I did add both to #nav

Comment: add overflow:auto

Comment: Added to #Nav and parent Main_nav.No change.

Comment: add like  #homepage { height: 500px;
overflow-x: hidden !important; }

Comment: I added it to the #header parent #main_nav and no change

Comment: It scrolls perfectly until the very end when it suddenly scrolls left

Comment: I disabled the nav script and widened the page. Now I see the header far out on the left. I checked for unbalanced tags and modified  the css and it still remains out on the left. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

use this code in your css

```
#homePage{
overflow-x: hidden !important;
}
```